# How make a click on a chromium browser link open in the default browser?

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded, tchromium

I want to achieve that when a user clicks on a hyperlink inside a TChromium browser page, the new page opens in his default browser.

Comment: In the `OnBeforeBrowse` event check if the `navType` equals to `NAVTYPE_LINKCLICKED` and if so, return True to the `Result` parameter (which will cancel the request for Chromium) and call e.g. `ShellExecute` passing the `request.Url`.

Comment: That is brilliant. Why didn't you post this as answer? Too unworthy for you? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [`OnBeforeBrowse`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs/projects/(default)/CefRequestHandler.html#OnBeforeBrowse) event check if the `navType` parameter equals to [`NAVTYPE_LINKCLICKED`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs/projects/(default)/cef_handler_navtype_t.html#NAVTYPE_LINKCLICKED) and if so, return True to the `Result` parameter (which will cancel the request for Chromium) and call e.g. [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) passing the [`request.Url`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs/projects/(default)/CefRequest.html#GetURL()) value to open the link in the user's default browser:

```
uses
  ShellAPI, ceflib;

procedure TForm1.Chromium1BeforeBrowse(Sender: TObject;
  const browser: ICefBrowser; const frame: ICefFrame; const request: ICefRequest;
  navType: TCefHandlerNavtype; isRedirect: boolean; out Result: Boolean);
begin
  if navType = NAVTYPE_LINKCLICKED then
  begin
    Result := True;
    ShellExecuteW(0, nil, PWideChar(request.Url), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: mabybe add an
"else
  Result := False"
?

Comment: Better might be `Result := False` at the beginning of the method, but it's not necessary since False is the [`initial result`](https://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/source/browse/trunk/src/cefvcl.pas#644).

Comment: You're right of course, but a nilled out parameter is more of an implied situation, with Delphi. :)

Answer (score 4):

In CEF3, `navType = NAVTYPE_LINKCLICKED` is no longer possible in the `OnBeforeBrowse` event, as in TLama's answer. Instead, I discovered how to detect this using the [`TransitionType`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/cef_transition_type_t.html) property...

```
procedure TfrmEditor.BrowserBeforeBrowse(Sender: TObject;
  const browser: ICefBrowser; const frame: ICefFrame;
  const request: ICefRequest; isRedirect: Boolean; out Result: Boolean);
begin
  case Request.TransitionType of
    TT_LINK: begin
      // User clicked on link, launch URL...
      ShellExecuteW(0, nil, PWideChar(Request.Url), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
      Result:= True;
    end;
    TT_EXPLICIT: begin
      // Source is some other "explicit" navigation action such as creating a new
      // browser or using the LoadURL function. This is also the default value
      // for navigations where the actual type is unknown. Do nothing.
    end;
  end;
end;
```